# IValueConverter That is supposed to freeze image for cross thread safe binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

My image binding keeps throwing this error:

> Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

I wrote a `IValueConverter` that I thought would resolve but it appears it is not.

```
public class FrozenImage : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource image = value as ImageSource;
        if (image != null)
        {
            if (image.Dispatcher != null)
            {
                if (image.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                {
                    ImageSource returnImage = new BitmapImage();

                    returnImage = image;
                    returnImage.Freeze();

                    return returnImage;
                } else return image.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture));
            } else return image;
        } else return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Did I miss something or is this just not possible?

Also tried a simplified version since dispatchers *should* not be needed and this has same errors as well:

```
public class FrozenImage : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource image = value as ImageSource;
        if (image != null)
        {
            ImageSource returnImage = image.Clone();
            returnImage.Freeze();
            return returnImage;
        } else return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is impossible as it looks like the exception is throwing BEFORE the `IValueConverter` has a chance to do its job... If anybody knows an alternative way to go about this that does not involve iterating the source collection and setting all the images to frozen please let me know.